# How can we prove that a plane without a point is homotopy equivalent or homeomorphic to a circle?

Tags: general-topology

How can we prove that a **plane without a point** is **homotopy equivalent** or **homeomorphic** to a **circle**?

I tried to do it this way: a *plane without a point* is homeomorphic to a *sphere without a point*, it in turn is homeomorphic to a *disk without a point*, and here I already think I want to say "Obviously, a disk without a point is homeomorphic to a circle," but I want to prove it, but I can't do it

The reasoning above will lead to nothing, initially the question was whether they are homeomorphic, this is not the case

Comment: Do you mean homotopy equivalent? They are not homeomorphic. One is compact and the other isn't.

Comment: Also, a plane without a point is homeomorphic to a sphere with *two* points removed, not one.

Comment: A plane without a point is not homeomorphic to a sphere without a point either.

Comment: A circle with a point removed is simply connected.  A punctured plane with a (second) point removed is not simply connected.

Comment: We may chose $0$ as point. Then plane without $0$ deformation retracts onto circle via $(t,v)\mapsto tv+(1-t)\frac{v}{\lVert v\rVert}$.

Answer (score 1):

Two topological spaces $X$ amd $Y$ are homotopy equivalent if there exist the continuous mappings $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Y$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to the identity mapping $i_Y$ on $Y$ and $g\circ f$ is homotopic to the identity mapping $i_X$ on $X$.

Now let $X=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ and $Y=\{ (x,y)\vert x^2+y^2=1 \}$. Let $f:X\to Y$ be defined as $f(x,y)=\left( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)$ and $g:Y\to X$ as $g(x,y)=(x,y)$.

Then $f\circ g=i_Y$ and $(g\circ f)(x,y)= \left( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)$, therefore it is enough to prove that $g\circ f$ is homeomorphic to $i_X$.

Define $H:X\times I\to X$ with $H((x,y),t)=t(x,y)+(1-t)\left( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)$ (equivalent to the deformation retract proposed by @freakish in the comment). Then, it is not hard to prove that $H$ is continuous and $H((x,y),0)=(g\circ f)(x,y)$ and $H((x,y),1)=i_X(x,y)$.

So, $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent.

However, $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic since a circle without a point is homeomorphic to an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, while a plane without two points is not!